# AngularJS: change json object values with input fields (with ng-click for instance)

Tags: html, json, angularjs

"myData" in the code below is a json object which I extract from $http.get response (I call the request when my web app is initialised). User has to be able to change the data, so I created the code below with inputs that are filled with values in this object.

```
<div ng-repeat="(parameter,value) in myData">
    <p>{{parameter}}</p>
    <!-- show only if val is defined (not 0 or null) -->
    <div ng-repeat="(par,val) in value" ng-show="val">
        <p>{{par}} : <input type="text" value={{val}}></p> <!-- val is the value the user can change, and par is  the parameter name such as in { parameter: "value" } -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I created the button that the user can click when he wants to save the changed data (ng-click="saveData()").

saveData function could then use $http.put(url,data) to update the data somewhere…

What I don't know is how to pass the whole object to the saveData() function ?
I know you can pass everything just by adding it like saveData(myVariableOrObject), but I don't see how I would do that in my case.

Probably I am missing something here, since I am fairly new with angularJS. Should my html inputs have some kind of ng-model there that would connect values to controller somehow? 
I would probably figure this out, but with the whole object, hm ? Would I need to construct the object in a controller function again or is there an easier approach?

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be glad.

If I was unclear please ask for more info.

Thank you!

Comment: Try onclick="saveData(myData)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myData[parameter][par]">
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing ng-form is good solution for this: 
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: hmm.. i think my double ng-repeat wouldn't work well with it? How would i define ng-model values?

Comment: You can define it as Matjaz answered `<input type="text" ng-model="myData[parameter][par]">` and pass myData object to ng-click function

Answer (score 1):

I've written a quick JSFiddle, which you can view here: http://jsfiddle.net/jakemulley/3AK79/1/

As you can see, the 'data' is linked to the `ng-model` attribute on both inputs, which means you don't need `value={{val}}`.

Also, which is probably worth noting, is that forms can have the `ng-submit` attribute, which calls the function inside upon submitting the form (in this case, `save(user)`).

**Note 1:** The data provided here can be replaced with your `http.get` data.

**Note 2:** By passing through 'user', you get both the username and displayname, which you can post to `http.put` as the data.

Does that help at all?

Comment: thank you, it did help, but unfortunately the exact ng-model answer above helped even more!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not `ng-onclick` it's `ng-click`.

Secondly, `{{val}}` expression is a one-way binding. Which means changes inside your input tag won't affect `val` variable. You will need to use ng-model for two-way binding. After that you can easily `ng-click="saveData(myData)"` or just `ng-click="saveData()"` and get values inside the controller with $scope.myData .

Comment: Yeah, i know, i wrote it correctly in my title, my bad :) thanks for your answer, though Matjaz's answer was directly what I needed